Getting Error Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement. in react native project
I'm working on the react-native project.
In a few screens, I'm getting the error "Error Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement."
I tried to fix this by checking some similar questions here but could not find anything to fix this issue.
Also, there is no conditional hook which is the general cause of this issue.
Please refer below code
import {
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {globalStyle} from '../../utils/styles';
import AppBar from '../../components/appBar/AppBar';
import {useTheme} from 'react-native-paper';
import MapView, {Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import {Box3} from '../../components/text/Box';
import {apiCallSecureGet, apiUrl} from '../../utils/api';

const HomeAddressScreen = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const mapRef = useRef();
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [addressData, setAddressData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    apiCallSecureGet(
      apiUrl.profile,
      response => {
        setAddressData(response?.data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Home Address api failed', error);
      },
    );
  }, []);
  const updateAddressHandler = () => {
    navigation.navigate('UpdateAddress');
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor={'blue'} />
      <View
        style={[
          globalStyle.appBarContainer,
          {backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary},
        ]}>
        <AppBar title={'Home Address'} />
      </View>
      <View
        style={[
          globalStyle.curveContainer,
          {backgroundColor: theme.colors.white},
        ]}>
        {/* add your content below  */}
        <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
          <MapView
            // ref={mapRef}
            style={styles.map}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            rotateEnabled={false}
            loadingEnabled={true}
            showsMyLocationButton={true}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: addressData?.profile?.lat || 24.6653189,
              longitude: addressData?.profile?.lng || 46.721565,
              latitudeDelta: 0.1,
              longitudeDelta: 0.1,
            }}>
            <Marker
              pinColor="green"
              coordinate={{
                latitude: addressData?.profile?.lat || 24.6653189,
                longitude: addressData?.profile?.lng || 46.721565,
                latitudeDelta: 0.1,
                longitudeDelta: 0.1,
              }}
            />
          </MapView>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.editContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={updateAddressHandler} style={styles.edit}>
            <Icon name="edit" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Box3 title={'Address'} text={addressData?.profile?.address} />
          <Box3 title={'Landmark'} text={addressData?.profile?.landmark} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default HomeAddressScreen;

Error is coming on line no 29, setAddressData(response?.data); when I set data into state.
